# Surface Integral calc 3

Tags: calculus, integration, surfaces

[image]

I am having difficulty setting up this problem. I know the bounds must be 0 to pi/2 for both theta and phi but I am unsure as to how to calculate the integrand. I know it must be the double integral of F*ds, but I do not know how to get F or ds. If anyone can help me set up the integral or give steps to follow so I can solve the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know how to parametrize a surface?

Comment: yes, would this be correct?: (8costheta*cosphi,8sintheta*sinphi,8cosphi)

Comment: No.  That's not correct.  The usual choice (though there are actually an infinite number of possible parametrizations) is $r(\theta, \phi) = \left(8\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), 8\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), 8\cos(\phi)\right)$ defined over $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $-\pi / 2 \le \phi \le 0$.  I suggest you look at [Khan Academy's videos on surface integrals](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/surface-integrals).

Comment: There are a lot of videos there, though.  So while I DO recommend you watch them, if you need to finish your problem soon, the only other thing you need to know is that $\iint_S F \cdot dS$ can really be thought of as a shorthand for $\int_{\phi_0}^{\phi_1} \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} F(r(\theta, \phi)) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\right) d\theta d\phi$.

Comment: Okay thanks so much for the help and the link! I will try this and see if I can solve the problem.

Comment: In this case would my (∂r/∂θ×∂r/∂ϕ) = 49sinphi?

Comment: Without even computing it I can tell you no.  That $\times$ is a cross product.  The result of a cross product is always a vector (technically a "pseudovector", but that's not important).

Comment: I apologize, I thought I had to get the norm of that vector. So the vector would have been 49<-costheta*sin^2phi,-sinphi*sin^2theta,-sinphicosphi> if I am correct.

Comment: Close: it's $-64(\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\phi), \sin(\theta)\sin^2(\phi), \sin(\phi)\cos(\phi))$ by my calculation.  BTW, it's far easier to read your questions/ comments if you [format them with MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: okay, so would it end up being: $\int_0^pi/2 \int_0^pi/2  F((8cos(θ)sin(ϕ),8sin(θ)sin(ϕ),8cos(ϕ)))*−64(cos(θ)sin2(ϕ),sin(θ)sin2(ϕ),sin(ϕ)cos(ϕ)) d\theta d\phi$

Comment: I tried, please forgive my inability to code correctly.

Comment: Your bounds of integration are not right.  Look up above where I gave them to you.  Then remember that $F(8\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), 8\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), 8\cos(\phi))$ is $F$ evaluated at $(8\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), 8\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), 8\cos(\phi))$ (which means "plug in those numbers for $x, y,$ and $z$ in $F$").  Then just take the dot product, evaluate a couple of integrals (you can use WolframAlpha to check yourself if they're difficult) and you're done!

Comment: No worries.  If you want to practice, just hit "Ask Question" and start typing in the text box.  The box below where you type will show you what your code looks like and you never even have to submit the question.  Also if you see someone else's code and you want to see how they did it: right-click on it and choose "Show Math As" and then "TeX Commands".

Comment: Ah okay, I see, and since it is just x^2 it will be $(8cos(\theta)sin(\phi))^2 $

Comment: And I will have to practice!

Comment: That's what your 3rd term will be once you "plug in" your $r$.  I think you should have it from here.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, I thought pi/2 because it is a hemisphere where z is positive.

Comment: Alright! Thanks so much for your time! You have really helped me so much !

Comment: To see why the bounds on the parameters that I gave you are correct, think about how the values will change as you change $\theta$ and $\phi$.  Consider if there is any part of the top half of a sphere that you can't represent by $r(\theta, \phi)$ with those bounds (spoiler: there isn't).  If you still don't see why after trying to visualize it, then check out those Khan Academy videos.  And you're welcome.

Comment: I was able to get the answer! thanks so much. I hope you don't mind I posted the link to your page in the answer to give you the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 2):

So after a lot of help from [Bye_World](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/137731/bye-world) I was able to come up with the correct answer:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi /2} \left[576\sin^2(\phi) \sin(\theta)+4096\sin^3(\phi) \cos^2(\theta) \cos(\phi)\right] d\theta d\phi$ which equals to $1024\pi$.